# How to match this string 'afa' but not 'bebeeeb' in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$s1='afa';
$s2='bebeeeb';

$s1=~/((\w)(?!\2))+\2?/;
```

This regex matches both of the strings.
I want to match only the first string. (The first character followed by any character but not the first character. The captured two characters can be repeated any number of times.)

Comment: Maybe `/^(?:(\w)(?!\1).)+\1?$/`? Not sure you need the `\1?` at the end: you added it to your pattern to allow an optional occurrence of the first word char at the end of the string, right? If "any character" means a word char, the `.` should be replaced with `\w`.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what the rules are — and why the second is not what you want.  Please explain more clearly, maybe with the help of a couple more examples (positive and negative) of what is wanted.  Would `dcdcdc` be OK? Would `dccc` be OK?  Would `cdefg` be OK?

Comment: Nice regex! https://xkcd.com/1313/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^(?:(\w)(?!\1))+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CEuO4K/2)

Answer (score 0):

Easier to check for the opposite.

```
# Doesn't contain repeated word characters.
$s !~ /(\w)\1/
```

Otherwise, you have to check *at every position*. (You were checking *at any position*.)

```
# Every character is a non-word character or a non-repeated word character
$s =~ /^(?:\W|(\w)(?!\1))*\z/
```

If the input can only contain word characters, the above simplifies to

```
# Every character is a non-repeated word character
$s =~ /^(?:(\w)(?!\1))*\z/
```

or even

```
# Every character is a non-repeated character
$s =~ /^(?:(.)(?!\1))*\z/s
```